# My SSL always give SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Tags: apache2

I have a VPN server runs apache2 and i am trying to generate server keys that will work with the SSL.

I am using this command lines:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout polszmata.pl.key -out polszmata.pl.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in polszmata.pl.csr -signkey polszmata.pl.key -out polszmata.pl.crt
```

I did set up a Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/polszmata
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/polszmata.pl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/polszmata.pl.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2 log looks fine no problems but the SSL certyficate not working right. Can someone point my mestake ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick heads-up:

Your certificte keychain to some CA every browser knows and trusts is non existant.  You have to create a CA first, and thrust that one in your browser, or import the public key that you created into the browser, so that trust is established.

Or you have to buy a key off a CA (or get one from https://letsencrypt.org/), and use that instead.

You can use the key you created to create a Certificate Signing Request, I'd guess that letsencrypt accepts those, signs them, and then you have to import that signature, and voila, the trust chain is there, and should work with many browsers, too (some may exclude the trust to letsencrypt, though... not an option for commercial use).